# Change feature colour and legend

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop

I am very new to GIS stuff, I am looking at a dataset displayed in WMS, I have attached the image of what it looks like. I want to change the feature colour of Mine and ERW to Blue and Pink respectively. I the link for the WMS is https://data.opendevelopmentcambodia.net/dataset/mineerw-casualties-2005--2013/resource/fda1f89d-6ba6-465f-b832-94c2c99c18f7

How would I go about changing the feature colours? There are a lot of different file types to download so I am very confused. [image]

Comment: You can't change WMS colours, since their display is controlled by the host.

Comment: Ok thanks, is it possible to download the dataset and use another WMS to set the colours to what I wanted?

Comment: Please read up on how WMS services work.

Comment: You can download the vector data (shp/kml/GeoJSON) from https://data.opendevelopmentcambodia.net/dataset/mineerw-casualties-2005--2013 QGIS will read them and you can style them as you wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the shapefile (other options available) from

```
https://data.opendevelopmentcambodia.net/dataset/mineerw-casualties-2005--2013
```

Unzip the shapefile and Load into QGIS

right click on the layer and symbology and classified by field (Mine Type in this case).

[image]

You can decide what size and colours you want for presentation.

QGIS 3.14 (Pi) used. The data has date fields so the temporal (new features) can be used for this data set if you wish to.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: Just a quick one, is it possible to classify two different fields? I want to show every ERW type as one colour and Mine type as another colour but it only displays one field at a time. Also it is possible to just do 1 colour for every point of a field?

Comment: Yes use the ID field that will give you. You can also merge two fields together to get the same effect.. Please ask/create another another question.